# Status Bar issue

Tags: iphone, ios, statusbar, navigationbar

As you can see from my image, the status bar is displaying on top of my table view and i don't understand what i have done wrong for this to happen. i am sure that it will be a simple fix and i'm just missing it.

Any help will be much appreciated, Thanks!

[image: In App View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can avoid this problem by writing below code in ViewDidLoad method...

```
  float SystemVersion=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

if(SystemVersion<7.0f)
{
//Currently your app is running in IOS6 or older version. So you need not to do anything.  
}
else
{
// Currently your app is running in IOS7. Do the following.

CGRect TempRect;
for(UIView *sub in [[self view] subviews])
{
    TempRect=[sub frame];
    TempRect.origin.y+=20.0f; //Height of status bar
    [sub setFrame:TempRect];
}
}
```

let me know it is working or not my friend!!!

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: Hey, that worked for my Status bar problem! i forgot to write something saying my navigation bar is displaying at the bottom in the second image. do you have a fix for that?

Comment: i'll just post another question for the navigation bar and accept your answer for the status bar. Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot man....!!! i am searching the answer for your navigation bar problem....

Comment: accepted the answer and changed my question, if there is a way to chat on this i'll do that instead of all these comments

Comment: yeh, i just dragged and dropped on the storyboard, i'm not using a controller

Comment: so, what you will have to do is make that custom bar's to connect on only upside....i am posting an image.Check that...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38547/discussion-between-fernando-and-niravpatel)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

like this.. In Autosizing of Custom bar...Only connect to upper side....

Let me know it is working or not!!!

Happy Coding!!

Comment: can you answer on this question, as i asked a new one so there wasnt to questions in one.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158759/navigation-bar-is-displaying-at-the-bottom

Comment: i answered you on that question, but please show me your view property on custom bar as i have posted(like this image).

Comment: hi Fernando, show me image of your navigation bar's View..like which i have posted on this answer.so me that image of navigation bar's view.