# Navigation Bar is displaying at the bottom

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, navigationbar

as you can see from the picture i have added, my navigation bar is displaying at the bottom of the screen under my table view. I have just dragged and dropped my navigation bar on to that view controller which means i'm not using a navigation controller. I don't understand why this is happening and i'm sure its a simple fix which i am missing.

image 2 is the storyboard view

image 3 view of the app running

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks!

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show me that View property of the custom bar in interface builder?

Comment: Seems to me that you put the `UINavigationBar` in to the `UITableView` as a `tableHeaderView`.

Comment: Just drag it outside of the table, you'll be fine.

Comment: can i post a picture in a comment? what do you mean Desdenova?

Comment: added image at the top of the question for you nirav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Delete your old navigation bar
2. Select your TableViewController and on top click editor->Embed in-> Navigation Controller
3. Now you should have a navigation bar on top.

Answer (score 1):

See screenshot. You dragged a navigation bar into your table. To achieve the behavior you want you can embed your view controller inside a `UINavigationController` and access your navigation bar via `self.navigationController.navigationBar`.

[image: Wrong UINavigationBar]

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem

What you have done is you have taken your navigation bar inside tableview...
that is the problem..

you just dragged that navigation bar outside that tableview...and that's it..